# Wordpress file permission

Tags: wordpress

How do I restrict registered users with editor role, from the Media Library upload file?

I have changed permission on the upload.php file but that does't work.

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a user role plugin, for example the excellent [User Role Editor](http://role-editor.com/).

Answer (score 1):

```
function remove_file_upload_cap_editor(){
    $role = get_role( 'editor' );
    $role->remove_cap( 'upload_files' ); 
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'remove_file_upload_cap_editor');
```

A better way would be to do this on plugin or theme activation as the values are saved in the database (if adding the code in a plugin). e.g.

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'remove_file_upload_cap_editor' );
```